# reading csv file with tensorflow

Tags: python, csv, tensorflow, tensor

In the examples. the variables for the columns in data set are manually given.
But my data set already has the names as headers. I want to use them. How to get the header names of a .csv file using tensor flow using python?

```
import tensorflow as tf
filename_queue=tf.train.string_input_producer(
['final_data1.csv'],num_epochs=1) 
#to reada the csv file----- 
print(5) 
reader = tf.TextLineReader(skip_header_lines=1) 
print(4)
_, csv_row = reader.read_up_to(filename_queue)
print(type(csv_row)) 
print(3)
with tf.Session() as sess: 
    print(reader.num_records_produced()) 
    tf.global_variables_initializer() 
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator() 
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord = coord)'
```

Answer (score -1):

I can't understand exactly what you try to do -- you need to give more details.

If you want to work with csv-file, I think you'd better use DataFrame data structure from pandas library. There is the method 'read_csv' where you can choose the row you consider as header.

Try it:

```
from pandas import read_csv
df = read_csv('YOUR_DATAFILE.csv',header=0)
print(df)
```

With parameter 'header' you can select what row in your dataset contains headers. In this case it's the first row.

Comment: Thank you Andrey, I did the same way before. But now, I want to do it in Tensor flow for classification. I read the data through it as shown in examples using TextLineReader. But when I am trying to get the no of records and getting headers of the csv file., it is showing me zero and I dont know how to get the data?.

Comment: Can you add to your post the code you wrote? It could be easier to help you with it.